# Custom block icon not appearing

Tags: piranha-cms

I am seemingly having an issue with my custom block's icon.

```
using Piranha.Extend;
using Piranha.Extend.Fields;


namespace NorthwindCms.Models.Blocks
{
    [BlockType(Name = "YouTube Video", Category = "Media", Icon = "fa fa-video-camera")]
    public class YoutubeBlock : Block
    {
        [Field(Title="YouTube video link URL: ")]
        public  StringField YouTubeVideoUrl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The custom block shows up, but without an icon: [screenshot of custom block without icon appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjPCH.png).

Does anyone have a tip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figured it out.

I had a look in Dev Tools and saw that Piranha uses the free licenses, so I checked what is available in those licenses and I managed to select the icons that I want.